# Content Sharing for Flink CEP

Tags: apache-flink, complex-event-processing

Is there any way to specify Apache Flink CEP patterns in a sharable format (Json, for example)?

My use case would be: developing a rule engine and allow users to customize CEP pattern without writing a lot of Java code, and to share patterns with other people easily.

Answer (score 0):

In Flink 1.7, CEP has been combined with Stream SQL to implement MATCH_RECOGNIZE -- see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html. This might be a good way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: how can I use StreamSQL to define a followedBy(..) logic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63858362/2000823 has an example.

Comment: Thanks David!  I submitted another question which bothered me for a while, can you help take a look? here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455895/watermark-fell-far-behind-in-flink-cep