# Apache Flink - calculate the difference of value between two consecutive event with event time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have some energy meters that will keep producing counter value which is a cumulative metric . i.e. Keep increasing until counter reset.

```
Key                Value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Sensor1            {timestamp: "10-10-2019 10:20:30", Kwh: 10}
Sensor1            {timestamp: "10-10-2019 10:20:40", Kwh: 21}
Sensor1            {timestamp: "10-10-2019 10:20:55", Kwh: 25}
Sensor1            {timestamp: "10-10-2019 10:21:05", Kwh: 37}
Sensor1            {timestamp: "10-10-2019 10:21:08", Kwh: 43}
.
.
.
```

There is a real-time ETL job which to do subtraction between two consecutive values in event time.

e.g.

```
10-10-2019 10:20:30  = 21 - 10 = 11
10-10-2019 10:20:40  = 25 - 21 = 4
10-10-2019 10:20:55  = 37 - 25 = 12
. 
.
.
```

Moreover, sometimes the event may not be received in order.

How can I achieve by using Apache Flink Streaming API? Better with example in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when faced with the requirement to process an out-of-order stream in order, the easiest (and performant) way to handle this is to use Flink SQL, and rely on it to do the sorting. Note that it will rely on the `WatermarkStrategy` to determine when events can safely be considered ready to be emitted, and will drop any late events. If you must know about the late events, then I would recommend using [CEP](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/cep.html#handling-lateness-in-event-time) rather than SQL with MATCH_RECOGNIZE (as shown below).

For more about using Watermarks for sorting, see [the tutorial about Watermarks in the Flink docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/streaming_analytics.html#watermarks).

Here's an example of how to implement your use case using Flink SQL:

```java
public class SortAndDiff {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

        DataStream<Tuple3<String, Long, Long>> input = env.fromElements(
                new Tuple3<>("sensor1", "2019-10-10 10:20:30", 10L),
                new Tuple3<>("sensor1", "2019-10-10 10:20:40", 21L),
                new Tuple3<>("sensor2", "2019-10-10 10:20:10", 28L),
                new Tuple3<>("sensor2", "2019-10-10 10:20:05", 20L),
                new Tuple3<>("sensor1", "2019-10-10 10:20:55", 25L),
                new Tuple3<>("sensor1", "2019-10-10 10:21:05", 37L),
                new Tuple3<>("sensor2", "2019-10-10 10:23:00", 30L))
        .map(new MapFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Long>, Tuple3<String, Long, Long>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple3<String, Long, Long> map(Tuple3<String, String, Long> t) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple3<>(t.f0, Timestamp.valueOf(t.f1).toInstant().toEpochMilli(), t.f2);
            }
        }).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                WatermarkStrategy
                    .<Tuple3<String, Long, Long>>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                    .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.f1));

        Table events = tableEnv.fromDataStream(input,
                $("sensorId"),
                $("ts").rowtime(),
                $("kwh"));

        Table results = tableEnv.sqlQuery(
                "SELECT E.* " +
                    "FROM " + events + " " +
                    "MATCH_RECOGNIZE ( " +
                        "PARTITION BY sensorId " +
                        "ORDER BY ts " +
                        "MEASURES " +
                            "this_step.ts AS ts, " +
                            "next_step.kwh - this_step.kwh AS diff " +
                        "AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW " +
                        "PATTERN (this_step next_step) " +
                        "DEFINE " +
                            "this_step AS TRUE, " +
                            "next_step AS TRUE " +
                    ") AS E"
        );


        tableEnv
                .toAppendStream(results, Row.class)
                .print();

        env.execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any plan for future to capture late events instead of dropping it and emit those late events to a separate sink (or any possible way to extract) in Flink SQL?

Comment: This is not yet on the roadmap. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10031.

Comment: If you do the data ingestion and watermarking using the DataStream API, it would be easy to use a ProcessFunction with a side output to capture any late events before doing further processing with the Table/SQL api.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this David, I was aware of side output in DataStream API. But interested to know about side output late events in Flink SQL. As some of my jobs are created using Flink SQL by BI engineers because of simple syntax, so interested to know about this. The JIRA link is exactly what I want. For now, I added myself as a listener to the ticket.

Comment: Thanks David, your solution works like charm. However when I use socketTextStream to simulate the sensor event, the latest two events always not being taken into account. That makes some delay on processing. I suspect it may related to watermark issue, but I tried withIdleness and setAutoWatermarkInterval config still no luck. Do you have any suggestion on  it?

Comment: Yes, this has to do with the nature of streaming, and how watermarks work. With bounded inputs (as I wrote the example), flink detects the end of the input stream and sends one final (very large) watermark that fires all event time timers. With an unbounded source, like a socket, then events can not be released from the sorter until a watermark arrives indicating that no earlier events are expected. withIdleness won't resolve this in cases where all sources are silent. If you need more help with this point, please ask a question about it -- there's too much to say to fit into a comment.